# Programmatically tell if chrome is working on opening a webpage?

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome

Is it possible to tell if google chrome is loading, or has finished loading the current webpage on the current tab?

Comment: If you are talking from Java well it doesn't have a way, nor does it really care if the browser has loaded the content. There are various ways on the client side such as DOMContentLoaded, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded,  and you could inform the server that it's done through an ajax request back to the server, but the real question is what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context? From where? A webpage? Use the [`onload` event hook](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) from within a webpage to fire a custom javascript function only when the page has completely loaded

Comment: From the host OS, I would like to run a java program the only output being "Chrome is not open/Chrome is open" and "Chrome is loading a page/Chrome is done/not loading a page".